# How to take the output value as an input and send it to servlet in java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I am trying to send some values from JSP page to a java servlet...

This is my JSP page:

```
<c:if test="${not empty LeavesOfAllMyTeam}">
    <li><td><b>Requests for <i>Aprob: </i></b> </td></li>
    <c:forEach items="${LeavesOfAllMyTeam}" var="entry">
        <li><td>Request with nr.  </td>

         <c:forEach items="${entry.value}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
                <b><c:out value="${item.nrReq}"/> </b> has
                <b><c:out value="${item.reqDays}"/> </b>days- <b><c:out value="${item.empFisrtName}"/> <b><c:out value="${item.lastNameEmp}"/> </b></b><input type="submit" value="OK" onclick="form.action='OKServlet';">
          </c:forEach>

    </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
```

I want the whatever the outputs are...there may be more, this should automatically create a submit button...then, the value displayed from that forEach should be sent to the servlet and there to get the result and insert it in DB

how can I achive this?

What should I put in my JSP page, and how to take that values in servlet?

This is dynamic because there may be 1 or 2 or more results in jsp pafe, that I need to display in my servlet, depends on the values that that forEach displays
Should I create a dynamic list of all the information from jsp and then send it to servlet?

This is my servlet:

```
**
     * Servlet implementation class OKServlet
     */
        @WebServlet(name = "OKServlet", urlPatterns = {"/OKServlet"})
    public class OKServlet extends HttpServlet {

        /**
         * @param request
         * @param response
         * @throws ServletException
         * @throws IOException
         */
        protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                     throws ServletException, IOException { 
            System.out.println("==================I'm in SERVLET OKServlet :===================");

            String result = request.getParameter("value from jsp page");


        }
        @Override
         protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                 throws ServletException, IOException {
             processRequest(request, response);
         }
         @Override
         protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                 throws ServletException, IOException {
             processRequest(request, response);
         }
         @Override
         public String getServletInfo() {
             return "Short description";
         }
    }
```

Comment: Can you shorten your question? The main question you want is?
"I want the whatever the outputs are... get the result and insert it in DB" this is very complecated. If you want auto submit data to server then using ajax and jquery. But at here you want to submit the value from foreach loop to server? Why you are doing that? JSP also a server side already! If your loop have value need to save to DB then put it direct to the server. The for loop in JSP should be use to write out some things in the web view for user interact.

Comment: The values are from db,but, to explain..I'm logged in as Team Leader, and that values from that forEach..those are the holiday leaves of my team.I can give them my OK  for the entire period,or I can give them for example from 5 days,only 2,or I can refuse the request. So,if I do any of the above,that information must go to settings table in db.If I press OK,it means that mu colleague in my team has all the days he asked,and he will see on his page that his request has been accepted totally,partially or not at all.This information must go in db because I need it for further statistics. Not ok?